# how pass a parameter to a listener?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, fullcalendar

I'm using `fullcalendar` with Symfony: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

In my calendar-settings.js I have an eventSource:

```
eventSources: [{
    url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    error: function () {},
}]
```

The listener **CalendarEventListener.php**:

```
class CalendarEventListener
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent) {
        $eventEntity = new EventEntity('title', $startDate, $endDate);
        $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
    }
}
```

Now I would pass a parameter from calendar-settings to the listener. Somebody know how?

I think it's anything with the data in `eventSource`, but I don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, you have a small bug in your listener, a missing `)` on the first line of `loadEvents()`.  Also, what do you mean by passing a parameter?  Is it something defined in the JavaScript file you are loading?

Comment: It's exactly that, I have a variable in my javascript and I need it in the listener to search with it in the database!

Comment: You have several options - if the parameter is never going to change, just define it in your config parameters and call it a day.  Or you could manually load the JavaScript file in your AppBundle's dependency injection component and set it as a parameter.  Whatever you do to get it as a parameter, just pass that parameter to your listener in the service definition.

Comment: In my calendar-settings.js, I have a variable, who change dynamically, that give the user connected. Then I need it in the handler, to look in the database juste the objects related with this user.

Comment: How does it change dynamically?  If it's dynamically-changing JavaScript then you should explicitly pass it back to Symfony

Comment: Yes, but my problem is how to pass it to symfony, how to pass it to the listener.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a listener at all, just pass the parametera to your AJAX request and handle accordingly.